# How to find the values for several variables so that a function returns highest value

Tags: machine-learning

I have 6 variables with values of something between 0 and 2 and a function, where these variables are given into. It predicts the result of a football match by looking at the past matches of both teams.

Depending on the variables, obviously, the output of the function changes. Each variable determines how much a certain part of the algorithm is weighed (e.g. how much less a game should be weighed that was 6 months ago compared to a game that was a week ago).

My goal is now to find out what the perfect ratios between the different variables and thus between the different parts of the algorithm are, so that my algorithm predicts most matches correctly. Is there any way of achieving that?

I thought of doing something like this with machine learning, something similar to linear/polynomal regression.
To determine how close a tip is I thought of giving:

- 2 points for when the tendency was right (predicted that Team A would win and Team A did win)
- 4 points for when the goal difference is right (Prediction: Team A
  wins 2:1, actual result: 1:0)
- 5 points for when the result is
  predicted correctly (predicted result: 2:1 and actual result: 2:1)

Which would make a loss function of

*maximal points for game* (which is 5) *- points for predicted result*

If I am able to minimize that, hopefully, after looking at some training sets (past seasons), it will theoretically score the most amount of points, when you give it a new season together with the variables computed in beforehand as input.

Now I'm trying to find out, by how much and in which direction I have to change each of my variables so that the loss is made smaller each time you look at a new training set.
You probably have to look at how big the loss is but I dont know how to find out which variable to change and in which direction. Is that possible and if so, how do I do that?

Currently I'm using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to use gradient descent to train your regression model.

Loss functions that you can use with gradient descent have to be differentiable, so simply giving/subtracting points to certain properties of the prediction is not possible.
A loss function that may be suitable for this task is the mean squared error, which is simply computed by averaging the squared differences between predicted and expected values. Your expected values would then just be the scores of both teams in the game.

You would then have to compute the gradient of the loss of your prediction with respect to the weights that the prediction function uses to compute its outputs. This can be done using backpropagation (details of which are way too broad for this answer, there are many tutorials available on the web).

The intuition behind the gradient of a function is that it points in the direction of steepest ascend of your function. If you update your parameters in that direction, the output of your function will grow. If this value is the loss of your prediction function, you want it to be smaller, so you go a small step in the opposite direction of your gradient.